# count of objects in 2 dimensional NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an NSArray inside an NSArray so:

```
@[
    @[ @1, @2, @3 ],
    @[ @7, @6 ]
 ]
```

How can I use the method `valueForKeyPath:` to get the number of items in each array, so this:

```
@[ @3, @2 ]
```

I have tried `[array valueForKeyPath:@"@count"]` but that provides the same answer as `[array count]` (so 2) as does `[array valueForKeyPath:@"count"]`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `@unionOfObjects` and `@count` KVC collection operators in conjunction:

```
NSArray *counts = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.@count"];
```

Logging `counts` in this case yields:

```
counts = (
    3,
    2
)
```

Calling `valueForKey:` and its variants on an `NSArray` instance typically is used to return an array formed from the result of calling `valueForKey:` on each element in the receiver. So, `[array valueForKey:@"count"]` won't return the value returned by `-[NSArray count]` but rather will call `valueForKey:@"count"` on each of its elements. Arrays nested inside others won't behave any differently, so we can't use `@"count"` as our key path directly as it will try to delegate that calculation to each of its elements. Using `@"@count"` as the key path won't work, either, because it operates on the key to its left, which is implied to be the receiver of the `valueForKeyPath:` method when no other key path is specified.

What we need is a way to specify that the `@count` operator should count not the enclosing array but the elements thereof. Using the `@unionOfObjects` collection operator in our key path accomplishes this. If we have a key path such as:

```
@unionOfObjects.$COLLECTION.$REST_OF_KEYPATH
```

Then the result returned will be the array formed by the results of sending each element of `$COLLECTION` a `valueForKeyPath:` message with `$REST_OF_KEYPATH` as the argument. One last fact - when the receiver of a `valueForKeyPath:` message is itself a collection, then `$COLLECTION` can be specified in the key path with the string `self`.

Accordingly, our key path should look like:

```
@"@unionOfObjects.self.@count"
```

This specifies that an array will be returned with each element being the result of sending `-valueForKeyPath:@"@count"` to each element in the receiver. Finally, and I'm not sure about the advisability of this, but it seems that self can be removed from the keypath entirely so long as the `@unionOfObjects` operator is not the only component of the key path. In this case, it substitutes for the `@unionOfObjects.$COLLECTION` component of the key path.

Comment: If anything that should produce 5??? (the union is performed, and then the resulting array is counted)

Comment: @Jonathan. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html). `@unionOfObjects` loops over the array and gathers all the following key paths (in this case the count of the objects in each sub-array).

Comment: @Carl you may want to peek at the link I gave above too. It explains this in more depth.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I re-read that, and then found [this](http://bou.io/KVCCustomOperators.html) and between the two I have a clearer picture of what's transpiring here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to "get" the number of items in each array (i.e. return a value, or just log it to the console).  Also, if you just want the number of items in each sub-array, `valueForKeyPath:` is not the message to be calling...

I'm going to assume you just want to know the count of each sub-array within the array.

You can use a for loop to iterate through each entry in `myArray` and send the `count` message to each entry.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ 
                      @[@1, @2, @3], 
                      @[@7, @6]
                   ];

for (NSArray *entry in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"array at index %lu has count %lu", [myArray indexOfObject:entry], [entry count]);  
}
```

Taking it a step beyond, instead of logging the values, you could store them in a variable to be used elsewhere in the program.